# What is the command or hotkey for stopping a running program in DrJava?

Tags: ubuntu, terminal, keyboard-shortcuts, java, programming

I installed `DrJava` about a week ago. Its been working fine so far but I ran into an infinite loop and wanted a way to stop the program from running without having to force `DrJava` to quit. Is there a command or hot key that would enable me to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To shut any command line program just type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd>.
It will look like this on the command line : `^C`

This is called an escape sequence.

**EDIT**
I think you may be able to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd> or ^D also

Answer (score 2):

There is a "Reset" toolbar command to the right of compile.  That will stop the running program in Dr. Java.